# How to masking date in textbox asp.net with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am Using textbox for input date user.
 How to auto masking when user input value date with format mask "dd-MM-yyyy"

Thanks

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352076/mask-for-asp-text-box-using-jquery will help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can use an ASP.NET `CompareValidator` to ensure the input is a valid date:

```
<asp:CompareValidator 
    id="cv_date" runat="server"  
    Type="Date" 
    Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
    ControlToValidate="tb_my_textbox"  
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date."> 
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: No this will ensure the text that's entered is a valid date. Using this, you could then format the values entered in your codebehind using DateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Comment: i'm using two language for my web. exist problem with this validator when switch to local language with other format date where i have format default for that for textbox is "dd/MM/yyyy". Tanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with the standard asp.net controls.
You might try ajax control toollkit, which is a set of ajax controls.  You can find out about it here:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Or you could build your own masking using javascript.

Comment: I'm not using ajax, i'm use textbox wit jquery datetimepicker.

Comment: You can write a custom function in jquery or javascript. Here is an example in another post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480979/jquery-masked-input-plugin-select-all-content-when-textbox-receives-focus

Answer (score 1):

you can try following JScript:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
   $('#txtbx').click(
     function() {
         $("#txtbx").mask("999-99-9999");
        });
  });
```